# how does the mark (in mark-and-sweep) function trace out the set of objects accessible from the roots?

Tags: c++, c, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand how the mark and sweep algorithm works practically in a piece of code.

I understand that every time I malloc(), my malloc() function adds the memory address to a linked list? Then when I want to garbage collect, I call the mark() function which takes in a "root" object and then marks all the reachable memory addresses from there. Then I call sweep() and it frees all the unmarked memory addresses.

I'm confused about what a "root" object is and how the mark function decides what objects are reachable from the "root" object.

I think it would really help me if someone was able to give me an small example of how the mark-and-sweep algo is working in a piece of code ... or maybe can point me to some reference which could because I can't find any.

Thank you.

Comment: I found this in a Wikipedia article on Garbage Collection: http://sourceforge.net/projects/meixnergc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's usually a root *set*, not just a single root object. The root set is basically all global variables, and all currently active local variables (e.g., all locals that are currently on the stack). One of the real difficulties with adding garbage collection to C or C++ is the possibility of failing to detect pointers in the root set (e.g., if you wrote a pointer out to a temporary file, where the garbage collector wouldn't know to look for it).

Figuring out what can be reached from there means any of those that's a pointer is examined, and what it points to is considered reachable. If what it points at contains one or more pointers, it follows those recursively, so all the things that can be reached from it are also considered reachable.

With a "precise" garbage collector, you have some sort of type information available to tell the garbage collector what things are pointers. For example, every object might contain a type tag to tell what kind of object it is. You then have a table to tell the GC where (if anywhere) what parts of that type of object are pointers.

With a "conservative" garbage collector, you simply look at contents of the data, and assume that if something *could* be a pointer, that it is. The only pointers you care about are those into the garbage collected heap though. For the sake of discussion let's assume a 64-bit pointers and an 8 megabyte GC heap. This means we look through memory and find anything with any of the ~8 million values that could be a pointer into the GC heap, and assume that any such value *is* a pointer, so whatever's at that address in the heap is considered reachable (and if so, we look for anything in it that could possibly be a pointer, recursively).

Although it initially sounds (to many people) like the latter would often treat *everything* as reachable, it actually works surprisingly well in real use. It does, however, prohibit certain garbage collection strategies. In particular, anything that involves compacting the heap means that all pointers to an object need to be adjusted when the object is moved--to do that, we *have* to be certain that what we're modifying really is a pointer to that object, not just some integer (or string, etc.) that happens to have a value that looks like it could be a pointer.

Comment: if object A points to object C in your code. How is that pointer translate into the linked list/heap of memory addresses?